# TypeDef Basic explanation

Tags: c, typedef

```
typedef size_t (CCAUTH_CALL *ccauth_sign_callback)(struct ccauth_handle *handle, const unsigned char *plain, size_t
size, unsigned char *buffer, size_t buffer_size);
```

could you please explain the line. I am getting this typedef line.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typedef for a function pointer.

It creates a type called `ccauth_sign_callback` which is a pointer to a function with arguments of types `struct ccauth_handle *`, `const unsigned char *`, `size_t`, `unsigned char *`, and `size_t`, and returns a value of type `size_t`

`CCAUTH_CALL` looks like a macro.  It probably adds compiler-specific attributes.